# Image Detection for expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, image-recognition, viro-media

I would like to include a feature in my app, where you can scan a certain picture and the app would recognise this image. Just like the image recognition feature in Viro: https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/ar-image-recognition . So I would set a certain image and it only needs to recognise this image.

I'm working with expo react native.

Does anybody have and idea how I might build this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly just make it call a python service on the backend and pass it the image and get back the result for it.

If you want to go serverless, you can even get a premade AWS lamda function, which you can call and pass it the image, and it'll do the processing for you.

In the end, it's better if you do this kind of processing on the server side, your app could get locked up because image processing can take time and you don't want that to happen on a mobile app.